# Bash script: Turn on errors?

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, debian

After designing a simple shell/bash based backup script on my Ubuntu engine and making it work, I've uploaded it to my Debian server, which outputs a number of errors while executing it.

What can I do to turn on "error handling" in my Ubuntu machine to make it easier to debug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- ssh into the server
- run the script by hand with either `-v` or `-x` or both
- try to duplicate the user, group, and environment of the error run in your terminal window 
   If necessary, run the program with something like "su -c 'sh -v script'  otheruser

You might also want to pipe the result of the bad command, particularly if run by `cron(8)`, into `/bin/logger`, perhaps something like:

```
sh -v -x badscript 2>&1 | /bin/logger -t badscript
```

and then go look at /var/log/messages.

Answer (score 2):

Bash lets you turn on debugging selectively, or completely with the `set` command. Here is a [good reference](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html) on how to debug bash scripts.

The command `set -x` will turn on debugging anywhere in your script. Likewise, `set +x` will turn it off again. This is useful if you only want to see debug output from parts of your script.

Answer (score 1):

Change your shebang line to include the trace option:

```
#!/bin/bash -x
```

You can also have Bash scan the file for errors without running it:

```
$ bash -n scriptname
```

Comment: @Industrial: I can be a lot more helpful if I knew what the specific error messages were.